# BigInteger NumberFormatException on valid big binary string

Tags: java, string, biginteger, numberformatexception

So, I was using BigInteger to convert some binary string to a numeric representation and ended up getting stuck on a weird error.

When this line is code runs, it raises a NumberFormatException:

```
BigInteger temp = new BigInteger(strbuf.toString(), 2);
```

where strbuf has the following string (made up only of zeros and ones):

```
"1001110000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010"
```

At first I thought perhaps the string or value were too big, but the following standalone java class compiles and runs just fine:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

class test {
    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        StringBuffer strbuf = new StringBuffer("1001110000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010");
        BigInteger big = new BigInteger(strbuf.toString(), 2);
        System.out.println(big);
    }
}
```

Is there something Im missing here? Why does the same code with apparently same values fail to run on my main application?

The exception message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1001110000000100"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.math.BigInteger.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.app.star.pad(star.pad:42)
```

Comment: invisible whitespace in the input?

Comment: Ran the code at IdeOne (http://ideone.com/GuJLLC) and got the following output (so I'm with @JanDvorak - must be something we can't see, like whitespace): 417930212607612468737110316986879612439672931440615354309603422963982626776659655589632258299793872789220031604756569181620845534282724833020726590169395583661276012623515415583708710670108499420513173862492847862152600326386627711243234204303044817195286706366016107594099186988482244150662103889346562

Comment: More exactly, I'm guessing a newline after `0100`. Note the input is truncated at this position.

Comment: Probably you have some mistake in a number. I have no error as others.

Comment: For extra clarification, the original string, which is copied at the post, comes from a method creating a string solely from 0 and 1. The one which runs in that snippet (and its working here too) is copied from what's displayed on the screen (using the clipboard). I'll check for any control characters inside the original string using regex, as Jan Dvorak suggested.

Comment: Just tried a replaceAll() to "" using "\\p{Cntrl}" and "[\u0000-\u001f]". Same error.

Comment: And just threw a "[^01]" to eliminate anything other than zeroes or ones, so its pretty much not an invisible whitespace issue...

Answer (score 0):

According to my safari book for j2ee5, there is an attempt (implicitly
suggested) to convert the value to *java.lang.Integer*, a wrapper for the
int type. That is the problem. Note the 2nd "at" line in the exception
unwind...

This may be an optimization problem..turn optimization off for your main
program not the cut-down demo program.

Sincerely,

ArrowInTree

Comment: How exactly can I do that? I don't see any options or flags in javac regarding optimizations, I also googled it and found no switches..

Comment: umm "man java" on linux... try -esa (enable system assertions) or -ea (enable non-system assertions) and/or -Xint (interpreted only mode...no bytecode compilation), etc.

Comment: I see.. I was looking for javac switches instead of java.. still I tried combinations of the flags you suggested, and also looked into the 'XX', but still stuck at the same exception. Thanks though.

Comment: Have you tried getting the debugger(jdb) out compiling with -g option? If you can get the source code, include that in the debugger's commandline or just download eclipse..?

Comment: For now I'm restricted to the closed JDK, and I'm interested in running my code in it; using OpenJDK to access the sources is not much of an option, though it would be interesting to see the differences in results.

I'm already using jdb btw, but have no access to Integer.parseInt or what's happening inside it since I dont have the sources.

Comment: This is, to me, a JDK implementation issue. Try separating out the StringBuffer->String reduction to its own variable and declare the variable const.